# How do you turn off IdentityServer3's built in UI views (login and registration)?

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0, thinktecture-ident-server, identityserver3, thinktecture

I'm trying to implement IdentityServer3 into my architectural mix.  I like the idea of registering Clients, Users, and Scopes.  What I do not like is using IdentityServer3's built in login and registration forms.

I have 4 different apps that need to use my IdentityServer3 implementation (aka TokenServer).  These 4 apps are AngularJs apps.  I have various C# .Net WebAPI services supplying data to these 4 apps.  Right now each of these 4 apps have their own authentication and registration process.  I need to consolidate authentication piece using IdentityServer3.

Each of these 4 apps have different account registration/authentication needs.  There's a mix bag of 3rd party authentication (Facebook, Google) as well as traditional forms authentication against an account the user has registered with.

So, I cannot have any of my AngularJs apps use the default Login/Registration forms that come with IdentityServer3.  I've spent a lot of time now trying to find a way to turn off the default views and just wire each of my AngularJs apps to my TokenServer.  I simply want to POST login credentials to the /token endpoint and return a token that can be used in subsequent calls to my WebAPI.  I want to replace the authentication process I have for each app with IdentityServer3 without changing the existing login/registration UIs.

I cannot find a sample app or even documentation that shows how to do this.  Is it even possible to 'turn off' every one of IdentityServer3's UI views and use my AngularJs client's login and registration forms?

Please point me in the right direction.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to use the OAuth 2.0 resource owner flow - which means - your app posts credentials to the token endpoint and gets back an access token. That is totally possible - you will miss out on some features like federation and SSO. But these are the known constraints of this flow.

If you want to use a redirect based flow (which gives you SSO and e.g. Google logins etc) - you need to redirect. You can replace any of the IdentityServer views with your own. The documentation and samples have plenty of information how to do that.

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/customizingViews.html

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/CustomViewService

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I will certainly look into these resources.  Do you know if the custom views are delivered via a pop-up or iframe?  I hope I can simply load these in my HTML flow without the use of an iframe or pop-up.

Comment: I'm looking through your CustomeViewService.  It appears these views are generated on the server.  My paradigm is server stuff should be REST.  Logins, logouts, registration are all UI activities and should be handled within your front-end code (AngularJs in my case).  Having a backend server serve UI content muddies the water in my opinion.  Is there anyway to achieve SSO, Google and Facebook logins, etc without relying on IdentityServer to serve the UI bits?

Comment: No. Same goes for Google and their ui.